# How to use butterknife to bind click event onto a view in a <include/> layout

Tags: android, butterknife

As we all know,if we want to use Butterknife to bind click event onto a normal view,we just need to declare the below method:

```
@onClick(R.id.yourview)
public void submit(){
     // do your things
}
```

But,how can I bind click event onto a view in a  layout.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is the same. You can do the same way:

```
@OnClick(R.id.yourview)
public void submit(){
    // do your things
}
```

When you have a  inside a XML layout definition Android inflate all the content into a viewgroup replacing the include.

So, the view id is valid to do a reference like the code above.

Comment: But if i have more than one same <include/> layout element,  the id will be duplicated.

Comment: You must avoid duplicated ids. You can do this adding preffix to id: login_yourview, subview_yourview.